# Issues while installing Composer and requiring frameworks

Tags: php, composer-php

I am setting up a small dev environment.

- Ubuntu 20.04
- PHP 7.4.3
- Composer 2.2.6

I have **Composer** installed.

```
 Composer version 2.2.6 2022-02-04 17:00:38
```

I am attempting to require **php-jwt**. I run `composer require firebase/php-jwt`. When I do this, I get the following **error**:

```
[Seld\JsonLint\ParsingException]
    "./composer.json" does not contain valid JSON
    Parse error on line 1:
    
    ^
    Expected one of: 'STRING', 'NUMBER', 'NULL', 'TRUE', 'FALSE', '{', '['
```

When I `cat composer.json` in my **working directory**, there is **nothing** in it. Are there **default options** that should be in **composer.json**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot have `composer.json` as an empty file, because an empty file is not a valid JSON object. (At a minimum, a valid JSON object looks like `{}`.)

Delete that file and run `composer init` to set up your project properly, or manually create it as a valid file following the documentation. (I recommend the init command over manual creation, because it will ask you a series of questions to help build the file.)